# Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 Refuse to Load Symbols for C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, symbols

For the last day or so, I've been struggling with a project that refuses to load the debugging symbols for the start-up project of a one-project Visual C++ solution for a conventional console mode application. The first line of the following log demonstrates the issue.

```
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\Source_Code\Visual_Studio\Projects\Actian_Pervasive_SQL\PSQLviaADOCPP\Debug\PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\bin\WWSYMBOL\CRTTime32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\bin\WWSYMBOL\NativeConssoleAppAids32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\bin\WWSYMBOL\NativeStringAids32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'.
The thread 0x4f64 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'.
'PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'.
The thread 0x4728 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2f60 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x23e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10676] PSQLviaADOCPP32.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Note, however, that symbols load for the dependent user DLLs, CRTTime32.dll, NativeConssoleAppAids32.dll, and NativeStringAids32.dll.

Several other applications, all running on the same machine, load symbols for their respective startup project, as the following example demonstrates.

```
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\Source_Code\Visual_Studio\Projects\NATIVE\DLL\CRTTime\Win32\Debug\CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\Source_Code\Visual_Studio\Projects\NATIVE\DLL\CRTTime\Win32\Debug\NativeConssoleAppAids32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\Source_Code\Visual_Studio\Projects\NATIVE\DLL\CRTTime\Win32\Debug\CRTTime32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\bin\WWSYMBOL\NativeStringAids32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\Source_Code\Visual_Studio\Projects\NATIVE\DLL\NativeConsoleAppAids\Win32\Release\vcruntime140.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'.
The thread 0x3dc0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'.
'CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'.
The thread 0x5ec8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x488c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5cbc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[11144] CRTTime_UnitTests32.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Below is the vcxproj file of the project for which symbols refuse to load.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>15.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{932DF08F-A55B-4339-9052-F5E01A709EA5}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>PSQLviaADOCPP</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>fals</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
    <IntDir>$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntDir>
    <TargetName>$(ProjectName)$(PlatformArchitecture)</TargetName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(SolutionDir)INCLUDE\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
      <DiagnosticsFormat>Caret</DiagnosticsFormat>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>false</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <ControlFlowGuard>Guard</ControlFlowGuard>
      <EnableParallelCodeGeneration>false</EnableParallelCodeGeneration>
      <EnforceTypeConversionRules>true</EnforceTypeConversionRules>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>false</RuntimeTypeInfo>
      <AssemblerOutput>AssemblyAndSourceCode</AssemblerOutput>
      <BrowseInformation>false</BrowseInformation>
      <SupportJustMyCode>false</SupportJustMyCode>
      <OpenMPSupport>false</OpenMPSupport>
      <ShowIncludes>false</ShowIncludes>
      <ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
      <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>StreamingSIMDExtensions2</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <OutputFile>$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)</OutputFile>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(SolutionDir)LIB\;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>CRTTime$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;NativeConssoleAppAids$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;NativeStringAids$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <LinkTimeCodeGeneration>Default</LinkTimeCodeGeneration>
      <MapFileName>$(OutDir)$(TargetName).map</MapFileName>
    </Link>
    <BuildLog>
      <Path>$(IntDir)$(TargetName).log</Path>
    </BuildLog>
    <Bscmake>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>false</SuppressStartupBanner>
    </Bscmake>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(SolutionDir)INCLUDE\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
      <DiagnosticsFormat>Caret</DiagnosticsFormat>
      <SupportJustMyCode>false</SupportJustMyCode>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>false</SuppressStartupBanner>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>false</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <InlineFunctionExpansion>AnySuitable</InlineFunctionExpansion>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <OmitFramePointers>false</OmitFramePointers>
      <StringPooling>true</StringPooling>
      <BasicRuntimeChecks>Default</BasicRuntimeChecks>
      <ControlFlowGuard>Guard</ControlFlowGuard>
      <EnableParallelCodeGeneration>false</EnableParallelCodeGeneration>
      <EnforceTypeConversionRules>true</EnforceTypeConversionRules>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>false</RuntimeTypeInfo>
      <OpenMPSupport>false</OpenMPSupport>
      <AssemblerOutput>AssemblyAndSourceCode</AssemblerOutput>
      <BrowseInformation>false</BrowseInformation>
      <ShowIncludes>false</ShowIncludes>
      <ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
      <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>AdvancedVectorExtensions2</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <OutputFile>$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)</OutputFile>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(SolutionDir)LIB\;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>CRTTime$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;NativeConssoleAppAids$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;NativeStringAids$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <LinkTimeCodeGeneration>Default</LinkTimeCodeGeneration>
      <MapFileName>$(OutDir)$(TargetName).map</MapFileName>
      <ImageHasSafeExceptionHandlers>false</ImageHasSafeExceptionHandlers>
    </Link>
    <BuildLog>
      <Path>$(IntDir)$(TargetName).log</Path>
    </BuildLog>
    <Bscmake>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>false</SuppressStartupBanner>
    </Bscmake>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(SolutionDir)INCLUDE\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
      <DiagnosticsFormat>Caret</DiagnosticsFormat>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>false</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <ControlFlowGuard>Guard</ControlFlowGuard>
      <EnableParallelCodeGeneration>false</EnableParallelCodeGeneration>
      <EnforceTypeConversionRules>true</EnforceTypeConversionRules>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>false</RuntimeTypeInfo>
      <AssemblerOutput>AssemblyAndSourceCode</AssemblerOutput>
      <BrowseInformation>false</BrowseInformation>
      <OpenMPSupport>false</OpenMPSupport>
      <ShowIncludes>false</ShowIncludes>
      <ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
      <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>StreamingSIMDExtensions2</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <OutputFile>$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)</OutputFile>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(SolutionDir)LIB\;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>CRTTime$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;NativeConssoleAppAids$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;NativeStringAids$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <LinkTimeCodeGeneration>Default</LinkTimeCodeGeneration>
      <MapFileName>$(OutDir)$(TargetName).map</MapFileName>
    </Link>
    <BuildLog>
      <Path>$(IntDir)$(TargetName).log</Path>
    </BuildLog>
    <Bscmake>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>false</SuppressStartupBanner>
    </Bscmake>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(SolutionDir)INCLUDE\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
      <DiagnosticsFormat>Caret</DiagnosticsFormat>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>false</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <ControlFlowGuard>Guard</ControlFlowGuard>
      <EnableParallelCodeGeneration>false</EnableParallelCodeGeneration>
      <EnforceTypeConversionRules>true</EnforceTypeConversionRules>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>false</RuntimeTypeInfo>
      <OpenMPSupport>false</OpenMPSupport>
      <AssemblerOutput>AssemblyAndSourceCode</AssemblerOutput>
      <BrowseInformation>false</BrowseInformation>
      <ShowIncludes>false</ShowIncludes>
      <ProgramDataBaseFileName>$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
      <EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>AdvancedVectorExtensions2</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <OutputFile>$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)</OutputFile>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(SolutionDir)LIB\;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>CRTTime$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;NativeConssoleAppAids$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;NativeStringAids$(PlatformArchitecture).lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <LinkTimeCodeGeneration>Default</LinkTimeCodeGeneration>
      <MapFileName>$(OutDir)$(TargetName).map</MapFileName>
      <ImageHasSafeExceptionHandlers>false</ImageHasSafeExceptionHandlers>
    </Link>
    <BuildLog>
      <Path>$(IntDir)$(TargetName).log</Path>
    </BuildLog>
    <Bscmake>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>false</SuppressStartupBanner>
    </Bscmake>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="PSQLviaADOCPP.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="resource.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="PSQLviaADOCPP.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <CustomBuild Include="PSQLviaADOCPP.mc">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">false</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <FileType>Document</FileType>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">false</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">false</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">false</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">mc -v -n -h $(ProjectDir)\res\ -r $(ProjectDir)\res\ %(FullPath)</Command>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Compiling Message Resources</Message>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename).rc;$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename).h;$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename)_1033.bin</Outputs>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">mc -v -n -h $(ProjectDir)\res\ -r $(ProjectDir)\res\ %(FullPath)</Command>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Compiling Message Resources</Message>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename).rc;$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename).h;$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename)_1033.bin</Outputs>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">mc -v -n -h $(ProjectDir)\res\ -r $(ProjectDir)\res\ %(FullPath)</Command>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">Compiling Message Resources</Message>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename).rc;$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename).h;$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename)_1033.bin</Outputs>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">mc -v -n -h $(ProjectDir)\res\ -r $(ProjectDir)\res\ %(FullPath)</Command>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">Compiling Message Resources</Message>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename).rc;$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename).h;$(ProjectDir)\res\%(Filename)_1033.bin</Outputs>
    </CustomBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResourceCompile Include="PSQLviaADOCPP.rc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup> for  the
</Project>
```

So far as I can tell, both projects are configured substantially alike, and the output PDB files are where they should be, alongside their respective EXE files. Due to space constraints, I must refer you to [The CRTTime GitHub Repository](https://github.com/txwizard/CRTTime) for that project file.

Suggestions welcome. Hailing frequencies are open and clear on all channels.

Comment: Few days ago I had a similar problem with debug and i solved it by changing configuration from x64 to x86

Comment: @user7769147 It just mean that you had an issue with the x64 project configuration. This is not a solution though...

Comment: Are you sure that the symbols are being created properly in the build process? You can try to load the symbols manually while in debug (in the GUI with the modules window), hopefully it’ll give you a more informative error.

Comment: Thank you @EnoshCohen for your most excellent suggestion. I found my way to the call stack window, where a right-click offered the option of loading the PDB. However, when I executed it, I was informed that "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder." This is consistent with the fact that Visual Studio for reasons unknown to me forced a new build, from which the PDB was strangely omitted. The upshot is that the EXE is nine hours newer than the PDB, and is, thus, seen as out of date with respect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Though I cannot say exactly what the issue was, I rebuilt the project from scratch, adding components one at a time until I had everything that was in it when I discovered that it wasn't loading its symbols or honoring breakpoints. Thankfully, it wasn't that big yet, and it won't be all that big when it's done, since it is just a little demo app, albeit a very expensive one at this point.